# Configuring Content for Editable Email Notification Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am using Editable E-mail notification to send email after a slave job is finished with the console output and test results as the email body.

I also need to add to the email direct link to the folder where build was actually built, is there an easy way to do this? maybe some kind of token? I didn't find any clues on how to get direct link to the build folder to display it location in the email.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, click the question mark <kbd>**?**</kbd> next to **Content Token Reference**, this will tell you all you need.

What "folder where build was actually built" are you referring to? The Workspace, or the build Archive?

For Workspace: `${PROJECT_URL}/ws/`
For Archive: `${BUILD_URL}/artifact/`

Comment: I was looking for a way to create a link to access the folder with files that was built during the job and provide it to the user on success by mail. The problem was that all "URL" tokens are returning jenkins local html pages when the thing i needed was folder from slave that was building the job where it stored all the files. I already found a way to solve this, by creating environment variable with path to the output folder on the slave and then adding some local variables like {project_name} + {job_name} + {date} to it. Solution is not perfect but it will do for now, thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Build output:
${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=1000}

For tests you can use the tokens as below:

There are ${TEST_COUNTS, var="total"} total tests of which ${TEST_COUNTS, var="fail"} test(s) failed.

**${FAILED_TESTS}** - Displays failing unit test information, if any tests failed.

For complete reference to Content token and arguments, click on help icon.

[image]