# How to add customized Token to Email in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I create a job to build android apk. and I upload apk to dropbox via linux shell and get the shared link successfully. The problem is,

**how can I add the link got from dropbox to email?**

I use email-ext plugin, and can send email. Also I checked the "Content Token", but don't know to how to inject the link.

I have checked the following link,

[Configuring Content for Editable Email Notification Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493574/configuring-content-for-editable-email-notification-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

It would be best, if you Write an Jelly Script and Store it under \email-templates in Your Jenkins installation. Then you could reference it using

```
${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="SomeJellyScriptName"}
```

in the Section

Default Content

See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Basic+guide+to+Jelly+usage+in+Jenkins

Then you can even use Environment Variables of the Build Process to reference them in sending the Mail.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used the plugin [Environment Injector](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject). The solution is the following,

1. The shell script write the shared link to a text file.
2. Environment Injector load the text file and inject as environment variable.
3. The environment variable in email template.